# Will this Cookie Checker reliably detect if user is accepting cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I want my page to set cookies on users in order to track when and if they return, and will be keeping their unique visitor id in a database.  I want to avoid creating cookie records for users which do not accept cookies (such as bots and crawlers), so I need a way to check if they are accepting cookies or not.  I've devised the following code.

```
private bool CookiesAreEnabled()
{
    bool result = false;

    HttpCookie CookieChecker = new HttpCookie("CookieChecker");
    CookieChecker.Value = "Do you see me?";
    CookieChecker.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10.0d);
    Response.Cookies.Set(CookieChecker);

    CookieChecker = new HttpCookie("CookieChecker");
    CookieChecker = Request.Cookies["CookieChecker"];
    if (CookieChecker != null)
    {
        result = true;
        CookieChecker = new HttpCookie("CookieChecker");
        CookieChecker.Value = "";
        CookieChecker.Expires = DateTime.Now;
        Response.Cookies.Set(CookieChecker);
    }

    return result;
}
```

It seems to me that this should detect that cookies are disabled, but it doesn't!  In my testing so far using Firefox with cookies turned off, the code reports that cookies are enabled!  Am I barking up the wrong tree as far as detecting if cookies are enabled?  Or am I making a newby-style mistake?

Comment: You cannot check for a cookie in this way with only one HttpRequest

Comment: @glammin, *how* would I do it, then?

Comment: i wrote how i will do it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if overall this code is right, but `Response.Cookies.Set(CookieChecker);` will set on response that browser is yet to receive and process. when you immediately after call  `Request.Cookies["CookieChecker"];` this examines current request you're processing - one that browser generated before even receiving Set-Cookie request.

At a minimum you need to let browser process response, then examine the next request to see if the cookie is there.

Comment: So, *how* would I let the browser process the response?  Do I have to try to set the cookie, then transfer to another page and do the checking there?

Comment: Right set a cookie and have browser to request another page, for example by issuing 302 Redirect to that other page.  In that page see if cookie arrives (make sure to handle cookie path accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use that approch the only way is to use 2 request: the first you set a cookie, the second you read it. You cannot do it with only one request.

Otherwise I think you can achieve it with javascript (this is a pseudo code):

```
/*first you check if there is already a cookie with the identifier*/
if(document.cookie.indexOf('cookiewithuniqueidentifier') == -1) {   
    document.cookie = 'testcookie';
    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf('testcookie') != -1) ? true : false;
    if (cookieEnabled) { 
        /*ajax request to the server for requesting an unique identifier*/
        /*save a cookie with that identifier*/
        document.cookie='cookiewithuniqueidentifier=936DA01F-9ABD-4d9d-80C7-02AF85C822A8'
    }
}
```